# Laravel 4 how to display flash message in view?

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to get my flash message to display.

This is in my routing file

```
Route::post('users/groups/save', function(){

return Redirect::to('users/groups')->withInput()->with('success', 'Group Created Successfully.');

});
```

This is in my view

```
{{ $success = Session::get('success') }}
@if($success)
    <div class="alert-box success">
        <h2>{{ $success }}</h2>
    </div>
@endif
```

But nothing is working.

When I try this, I get an error Variable $success is undefined. But it actually shows the flash message too.

```
{{ Session::get('success') }}
@if($success)
    <div class="alert-box success">
        <h2>{{ $success }}</h2>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: when you use `->with()` it doesn't set the session in the flash, rather it creates an variable, so in your case just use $session instead of Session::get()

Comment: I get $session undefined :(

Comment: SORRY typo its $success

Comment: Yes thats what I thought but I also get Undefined variable: success

Comment: you have to do @if(isset($success)),because you are calling the same view once with success variable and once without it

Comment: Now I get nothing, I have it like this @if(isset($success))
    <div class="alert-box success">
        <h2>{{ $success }}</h2>
    </div> Could it be my xampp that has an issue?
@endif

Comment: the message will be shown only after post request

Answer (score 56):

This works for me

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert-box success">
        <h2>{{ Session::get('success') }}</h2>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: I've actually tried this and still nothing, could it be something wrong with my xampp installation? Do I need to edit anything in my php ini file?

Comment: No, you do not need to update your php.ini file. This should work out of the box.

Comment: I clearly see, you are not doing it wrong at all. Try to take a look at this once again, maybe it helps http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects

Comment: @MorneZeelie can you clarify "not working at all" please ? Are you getting error messages (please post them) or weird results (explain what you see). Andreayco's answer is perfect.

Comment: @Alex-Info.net What I mean by this is that it's blank. Nothing is showing not even errors.

Comment: Many core functions, such as password reset functionality, put a boolean "true" into session variables "success" and "error". This means you cannot just assume they will contain a printable message. It seems flash data in many examples and tutorials are used inconsistently, largely because Laravel is still a moving target as it slowly settles down.

Answer (score 6):

if you are using **bootstrap-3** try the script below for Alert Style

```
    @if(Session::has('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <h2>{{ Session::get('success') }}</h2>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 4):

when you set variable or message using `->with()` it doesn't set the variable/message in the session flash, rather it creates an variable which is available in your view, so in your case just use `$success` instead of `Session::get('success')`

And in case you want to set the message in the session flash the use this `Session::flash('key', 'value');` but remember with session flash the data is available only for next request.

Otherwise you can use `Session::put('key', 'value');` to store in session

for more info [read here](http://laravel.com/docs/session)

Comment: Part of your answer is wrong. If you are using `Redirect::to()` with `with()` then it will be assigned to the session. See http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects

Answer (score 4):

two methods:

Method 1 - if you're using

```
return Redirect::to('users/groups')->withInput()->with('success', 'Group Created Successfully.');
```

under your controller create(), add in

```
$success = Session::get('success');
return View::make('viewfile')->with('success', $success);
```

then on view page,

```
@if (isset($success))
{{$success }}
@endif
```

What's happening in method 1 is that you're creating a variable $success that's passed into your create(), but it has no way of display $success. isset will always fail unless you set a variable to get the message and return it.

Method 2 - use return Redirect withFlashMessage

```
return Redirect::route('users/groups')->withFlashMessage('Group Created Successfully.');
```

then on your view page,

```
@if (Session::has('flash_message'))
{{ Session::get('flash_message') }}
@endif
```

Method 2 is much cleaner and does not require additional code under create().

Comment: Can you tell me the API of withFlashMessage ?

Answer (score 3):

```
{{ Session::get('success') }}
```

This just echos the session variable 'success'. So when you use

`{{ Session::get('success') }}
@if($success)
    <div class="alert-box success">
        <h2>{{ $success }}</h2>
    </div>
@endif`

you are seeing it's output along with the error of the next statement. Because with() function only sets the value in Session and will not set as a variable. Hence `@if($success)` will result in undefined variable error.

As @Andreyco said,

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
<div class="alert-box success">
    <h2>{{ Session::get('success') }}</h2>
</div>
@endif
```

This should work.

The reason you are not seeing it might be because the action you are performing is not success. And this does not require you to either reinstall xampp or modify php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 4.2
Personally i use

```
Session::flash('key', 'value');
return Redirect::to('some/url');
```

then in the view id first check if there is a session of that key in the view

```
@if(Session::has('key'))
   {{Session::get('key')}} //this prints out the message or your 'value' in the session::flash method
@endif
```

it works for me most of the time and i usually have that blade template integrated into my view just so i can push success messages to the view from my codes.

please do note that it is stated in the documentation that "Sometimes you may wish to store items in the session only for the next request. You may do so using the Session::flash method" so yes it expires after the next page.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i just realized in using the Redirect::to(), when you use the withInput() method, chaining a with() function to pass variables will not work. the only way is either you flash your inputs separately using Input::flash(), and use the with() to pass your variables or you pass your variable via session using Session::flash('key','val') and retrieve in the view via session::get('key').

Answer (score 0):

This link describes how to do this http://vegibit.com/flash-messages-in-laravel/

Just tried with laravel 5 - works to me.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the routes.php file try to create your routes within the

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //routes here
}
```

then use

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
   <div class="alert-box success">
     <h2>{{ Session::get('success') }}</h2>
   </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score -3):

I fixed mine by changing the session driver in config/session.php from **array** to **file**  !