# Laravel - Returning to varying jquery form after validation

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

Im wondering if i can some help.

I have a form which switches form elements using jQuery based on a dropdown value.

Like so

```
<select id="type">
    <option value="a">Account</option>
    <option value="b">Insurance</option>
    <option value="c">Other</option>
</select>

<div id="a" class="box">
    <input type="text" name="accname" />
</div>

<div id="b" class="box">
    <input type="text" name="insnum" />
</div>

<div id="c" class="box">
    <input type="text" name="othername" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.box').hide();
        $('#a').show();
        $('#type').change(function(){
            $('.box').hide();
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my controller i use a switch statement to do the validation, like so:

```
$typeCheck = Input::get('type');

switch ( $typeCheck ) {

    case "a":
        // Validation here
        break;

    case "b":
        // Validation here
        break;

    case "c":
        // Validation here
        break;

}
```

The problem im having, is if the validation fails, it goes back to the original page load setting and displays the first textbox.

So, if i clicked 'Other' from the dropdown, didnt enter anything, and hit submit ... It will return the error 'You didnt enter anything in the Other textbox', BUT will display the Account textbox.

If the validator fails, this is the code im using to send it back

```
return Redirect::to('page-name')
    ->withErrors($v)
    ->withInput();
```

Is there any way i could maybe send the 'Type' value back to the form, and then do a check to make it display that option?

Im stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the session functionality:
http://laravel.com/docs/session

Normally you can read your type value via Session::get(type)

Similar question with Redirects and reentering values can be found here [Laravel 4 how to display flash message in view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527182/laravel-4-how-to-display-flash-message-in-view)